# =PRINTF("{1} - {2}", ... ) in Excel without VBA - LAMBDA functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: array, vba, excel, comparative-review, lambda

The TEXTJOIN function has a really nice interface:

```swift
=TEXTJOIN(delimiter, ignore_empty, text1, [text2], …, [text252])
```

... where `text2` onwards are optional args, and each text argument can be a string (hardcoded or function return) *or an array of strings* (from a range or an array formula). This lets you call the function in a few ways:

```swift
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, "The", "sun", "will", "come", "up", "tomorrow.") //comma separated values
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, A2:A8) //A 1D array
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, {1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9}) //2D array
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, A2:A8, "foo", A1:B3, "bar") //Combo!
```

---

`TEXTJOIN` is an example of a ***variadic** function* - one which can accept any number of arguments - and in VBA we have the `ParamArray` modifier to create variadic functions. Here however, I wanted to create a PRINTF LAMBDA function which implements a similar interface without using VBA, e.g. :

```swift
=PRINTF(mask, text1, [text2], …) //mask like "foo {1} bar {2}"
```

... but LAMBDA functions have no ParamArray type like VBA does to accept a variable number of args, and no ability to loop through their arguments either. Nevertheless, the [new `[optional]` syntax](https://insider.office.com/en-gb/blog/new-lambda-functions-available-in-excel#:%7E:text=LAMBDA%20improvements,value%20of%20param2.) combined with the `ISOMITTED` function *can* be used to define LAMBDAs with variable number of arguments so with that this is what I made:

#### `PRINTF`:

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    _0,[_1],[_2],[_3],[_4],[_5],[_6],[_7],[_8],[_9],[_10],[_11],[_12],[_13],[_14],[_15],[_16],[_17],[_18],[_19],[_20],[_21],[_22],[_23],[_24],[_25],[_26],[_27],[_28],[_29],[_30],[_31],[_32],[_33],[_34],[_35],[_36],[_37],[_38],[_39],[_40],[_41],[_42],[_43],[_44],[_45],[_46],[_47],[_48],[_49],[_50],[_51],[_52],[_53],[_54],[_55],[_56],[_57],[_58],[_59],[_60],[_61],[_62],[_63],[_64],[_65],[_66],[_67],[_68],[_69],[_70],[_71],[_72],[_73],[_74],[_75],[_76],[_77],[_78],[_79],[_80],[_81],[_82],[_83],[_84],[_85],[_86],[_87],[_88],[_89],[_90],[_91],[_92],[_93],[_94],[_95],[_96],[_97],[_98],[_99],[_100],[_101],[_102],[_103],[_104],[_105],[_106],[_107],[_108],[_109],[_110],[_111],[_112],[_113],[_114],[_115],[_116],[_117],[_118],
    LET(
        tokensArray,
        FLATARRAY(
            _0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30, _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, _71, _72, _73, _74, _75, _76, _77, _78, _79, _80, _81, _82, _83, _84, _85, _86, _87, _88, _89, _90, _91, _92, _93, _94, _95, _96, _97, _98, _99, _100, _101, _102, _103, _104, _105, _106, _107, _108, _109, _110, _111, _112, _113, _114, _115, _116, _117, _118
        ),
        escapedResult,
        _ReplaceRecursive(
            mask,
            tokensArray,
            1,
            ROWS(tokensArray)
        ),
        SUBSTITUTE(escapedResult,"\}","}")
    )
)
```

Yes, some hardcoded arguments - a bit nasty but not too bad. Some points to note:

- The first argument `_0` is mandatory, this is because my `FLATARRAY` function (I'll get onto that) must return an array with at least one element. Still calling `PRINTF(mask)` with no argument would be a redundant noop anyway so I think this is an okay API.
- The number of arguments could be [up to 253](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enter%20up%20to%20253%20parameters), however the name manager has a character limit of 2000 for me and some of the LAMBDAS are too long to support more args. I think 100 is more than sufficient anyway (bear in mind each arg could itself be a whole array of values, like in `TEXTJOIN`).

---

That `PRINTF` function relies on a `_ReplaceRecursive` function to do the legwork:

#### `_ReplaceRecursive`:

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    tokens,
    i,
    tokenCount,
    IF(
        i > tokenCount,
        mask,
        LET(
            token,
            INDEX(tokens,i),
            escapedToken,
            SUBSTITUTE(token,"}","\}"),
            inIndexedMode,
            ISERROR(
                FIND("{}",mask,1)
            ),
            substituted,
            IF(
                inIndexedMode,
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{" & i & "}",
                    escapedToken
                ),
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{}",
                    escapedToken,
                    1
                )
            ),
            _ReplaceRecursive(
                substituted,
                tokens,
                i + 1,
                tokenCount
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Some notes:

- I've gone with an _PascalCase naming system for this private implementation LAMBDA as opposed to YELLCASE for the Excel UDF entry point.
- The function has 2 modes; "{indexed}" where you provide the 1-based location in the tokensArray of the string you wish to substitute, and {} positional. More explanation over on my stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69266041/6609896). It has some basic escaping although it will incorrectly handle the edge case of `\}` in the mask, not sure if there's an easy fix for this, open to suggestions.

---

### Mimicking ParamArray

The other aspect of the PRINTF function is the argument handling, and this is where things start to get a bit messy...

#### `FLATARRAY`:

A helper function for taking an array of arrays and flattening it into a 1D vector.

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    _0,[_1],[_2],[_3],[_4],[_5],[_6],[_7],[_8],[_9],[_10],[_11],[_12],[_13],[_14],[_15],[_16],[_17],[_18],[_19],[_20],[_21],[_22],[_23],[_24],[_25],[_26],[_27],[_28],[_29],[_30],[_31],[_32],[_33],[_34],[_35],[_36],[_37],[_38],[_39],[_40],[_41],[_42],[_43],[_44],[_45],[_46],[_47],[_48],[_49],[_50],[_51],[_52],[_53],[_54],[_55],[_56],[_57],[_58],[_59],[_60],[_61],[_62],[_63],[_64],[_65],[_66],[_67],[_68],[_69],[_70],[_71],[_72],[_73],[_74],[_75],[_76],[_77],[_78],[_79],[_80],[_81],[_82],[_83],[_84],[_85],[_86],[_87],[_88],[_89],[_90],[_91],[_92],[_93],[_94],[_95],[_96],[_97],[_98],[_99],[_100],[_101],[_102],[_103],[_104],[_105],[_106],[_107],[_108],[_109],[_110],[_111],[_112],[_113],[_114],[_115],[_116],[_117],[_118],[_119],
    LET(
        indexable,
        LAMBDA(
            myIndex,
            CHOOSE( //this will create an array with default values for omitted args
                myIndex,
                _1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100,_101,_102,_103,_104,_105,_106,_107,_108,_109,_110,_111,_112,_113,_114,_115,_116,_117,_118,_119
            )
        ),
        argsSize,
        ARGSCOUNT(
            _1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63
        ) +
        ARGSCOUNT( //have to split because of argument limits in ARGSCOUNT()
            _64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100,_101,_102,_103,_104,_105,_106,_107,_108,_109,_110,_111,_112,_113,_114,_115,_116,_117,_118,_119
        ),
        joiner, //a function to merge all the args into a single array using an accumulator
        LAMBDA(
            runningTot,
            x,
            ARRAYJOIN(
                runningTot,
                indexable(x)
            )
        ),
        base,
        FLATTEN(_0), //flatten the first arg so its dimensions are still consistently 1D when it's the only arg
        IF(
            argsSize = 0,
            base,
            REDUCE(
                base,
                SEQUENCE(argsSize),
                joiner
            )
        )
    )
```

The principle here is that `CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(n), arg_1, arg_2 ... arg_n)` constructs an array with n items. However we don't know the value of `n`, so instead I use `CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(m), arg_1, arg_2, ... arg_n)` with

- `n` optional arguments to my LAMBDA
- `m` actually supplied (e.g. TEXTJOIN has n = 252, but I can call it passing m = 3 items to join)
- `m<=n`

So how do you evaluate `m` the number of arguments passed? That is the subject of a question I asked on SO: [Create dynamic array from non-contiguous cells/values without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69319638/6609896) but what I ultimately went for was a hardcoded binary search to find the index of the first omitted argument without checking all of them (this works because if the 6th argument is omitted, I know all the arguments from 7 onwards will be as well). This is the resulting function:

```swift
=LAMBDA([p_1],[p_2],[p_3],[p_4],[p_5],[p_6],[p_7],[p_8],[p_9],[p_10],[p_11],[p_12],[p_13],[p_14],[p_15],[p_16],[p_17],[p_18],[p_19],[p_20],[p_21],[p_22],[p_23],[p_24],[p_25],[p_26],[p_27],[p_28],[p_29],[p_30],[p_31],[p_32],[p_33],[p_34],[p_35],[p_36],[p_37],[p_38],[p_39],[p_40],[p_41],[p_42],[p_43],[p_44],[p_45],[p_46],[p_47],[p_48],[p_49],[p_50],[p_51],[p_52],[p_53],[p_54],[p_55],[p_56],[p_57],[p_58],[p_59],[p_60],[p_61],[p_62],[p_63],IF(ISOMITTED(p_32),IF(ISOMITTED(p_16),IF(ISOMITTED(p_8),IF(ISOMITTED(p_4),IF(ISOMITTED(p_2),IF(ISOMITTED(p_1),0,1),IF(ISOMITTED(p_3),2,3)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_6),IF(ISOMITTED(p_5),4,5),IF(ISOMITTED(p_7),6,7))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_12),IF(ISOMITTED(p_10),IF(ISOMITTED(p_9),8,9),IF(ISOMITTED(p_11),10,11)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_14),IF(ISOMITTED(p_13),12,13),IF(ISOMITTED(p_15),14,15)))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_24),IF(ISOMITTED(p_20),IF(ISOMITTED(p_18),IF(ISOMITTED(p_17),16,17),IF(ISOMITTED(p_19),18,19)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_22),IF(ISOMITTED(p_21),20,21),IF(ISOMITTED(p_23),22,23))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_28),IF(ISOMITTED(p_26),IF(ISOMITTED(p_25),24,25),IF(ISOMITTED(p_27),26,27)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_30),IF(ISOMITTED(p_29),28,29),IF(ISOMITTED(p_31),30,31))))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_48),IF(ISOMITTED(p_40),IF(ISOMITTED(p_36),IF(ISOMITTED(p_34),IF(ISOMITTED(p_33),32,33),IF(ISOMITTED(p_35),34,35)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_38),IF(ISOMITTED(p_37),36,37),IF(ISOMITTED(p_39),38,39))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_44),IF(ISOMITTED(p_42),IF(ISOMITTED(p_41),40,41),IF(ISOMITTED(p_43),42,43)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_46),IF(ISOMITTED(p_45),44,45),IF(ISOMITTED(p_47),46,47)))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_56),IF(ISOMITTED(p_52),IF(ISOMITTED(p_50),IF(ISOMITTED(p_49),48,49),IF(ISOMITTED(p_51),50,51)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_54),IF(ISOMITTED(p_53),52,53),IF(ISOMITTED(p_55),54,55))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_60),IF(ISOMITTED(p_58),IF(ISOMITTED(p_57),56,57),IF(ISOMITTED(p_59),58,59)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_62),IF(ISOMITTED(p_61),60,61),IF(ISOMITTED(p_63),62,63)))))))
```

... or for a more manageable number of arguments:

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    [_1],[_2],[_3],[_4],[_5],[_6],[_7],
    IF(
        ISOMITTED(_4),
        IF(
            ISOMITTED(_2),
            IF(
                ISOMITTED(_1),
                0,
                1
            ),
            IF(
                ISOMITTED(_3),
                2,
                3
            )
        ),
        IF(
            ISOMITTED(_6),
            IF(
                ISOMITTED(_5),
                4,
                5
            ),
            IF(
                ISOMITTED(_7),
                6,
                7
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Hopefully you can see how that decision tree cuts down on the number of arguments that have to be checked with `ISOMITTED()`. This function was hit hard by the character limit so is limited to only 63 args (it has to be a power of two - 1 for the binary tree to be symmetric, which is easier to programme)

And finally, there are a couple of helper functions:

#### `FLATTEN:`

Convert 2D array to 1D array

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    array,
    LET(
        r, ROWS(array),
        c, COLUMNS(array),
        INDEX(
            array,
            ROUNDUP(
                SEQUENCE(
                    r * c
                ) / c,
                0
            ),
            MOD(
                SEQUENCE(
                    r * c,
                    ,
                    0
                ),
                c
            ) + 1
        )
    )
)
```

<sub>([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/oo29mp/comment/h5vkupe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))</sub>

#### `ARRAYJOIN`

Merge two arrays into a single 1D array - like a `For...Each` over both ranges in a row...

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    a,
    b,
    LET(
        flatA, FLATTEN(a),
        flatB, FLATTEN(b),
        sizeA, ROWS(flatA),
        sizeB, ROWS(flatB),
        joinedIndexable,
        LAMBDA(
            x,
            IF(
                x <= sizeA,
                INDEX(
                    flatA,
                    x
                ),
                INDEX(
                    flatB,
                    x - sizeA
                )
            )
        ),
        joinedIndexable(
            SEQUENCE(
                sizeA + sizeB
            )
        )
    )
)
```

For contrast, the equivalent VBA (without flattening) looks like:

```vb
Public Function ARRAYFROMARGS(ParamArray args()) As Variant
    ARRAYFROMARGS = args
End Function
```

That looks really bad I know, but actually now I have those helper functions, implementing ParamArray in another lambda is as simple as defining n optional args and passing them to `FLATARRAY` and it can filter out the omitted ones automatically. I also have a simpler `ARRAY` function which does not flatten the args (so same as the VBA), but that doesn't match the TEXTJOIN behaviour I'm after. Code for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328652/6609896).

Answer (score 1):

Very nice! It can be simplified, since you don't need `_ReplaceRecursive`. I subbed in a `REDUCE` like this and this and it seems ok, assuming we don't have to escape the tokens.

```swift
REDUCE(
     mask,
     SEQUENCE(ROWS(tokensArray)),
     LAMBDA(acc,i,
         SUBSTITUTE(
             acc,
             "{" & i & "}",
             INDEX(tokensArray,i)
         )
     )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks:) Yeah wrote the Printf function itself before Reduce was announced but I was thinking it simplifies things a little (didn't want to modify the question though). The escaping lets you use `PRINTF("mask {1}, {2}", "foo {2}", "bar")` i.e. a `{}` placeholder in a substitute token. Without escaping yo get `"mask foo bar, bar"` not `"mask foo {2}, bar"`. However with this approach you can't have `\}` intentionally in the mask as it will become `}` which is an edge case, can't think of an easy workaround though.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks for the clarification!